# Visio Sequence Diagrams: How to remove the underline

Tags: microsoft-visio, uml

I don't see a way to remove the underline in the Object Lifelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Visio **Drawing Explorer** window, open the appropriate foreground page, scroll down to your **Object Lifeline** shape, expand to show its shapes, select the **Object** shape, then from the menu/ribbon turn off Underline.